# Does position: relative not work with <td>?

Tags: html, css

Can I say that

```
position: relative;
```

does not work with `<td>`? http://jsfiddle.net/nX7T6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I say that `position: relative` doesn't work with `<td>`?

I think [you can](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position).

> The effect of `position:relative` on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Create div tag inside of td and style the dive tag as

> posiotion:relative

```
<style>
td div{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
}

span.data{
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    left:2px;
    background-color#ffffff;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <div>
             <span class='data'>Position absolute</span>
         </div>
        <td>

        <td>
         <div>
             Normal
         </div>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```